# Highlighting specific nodes in a jtree depending on data stored in the node

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treecellrenderer

I have an application that displays a jTree. Each node in the tree has a boolean field called `flagged` which indicates whether it requires attention or not from the user.

If the field is `true`, then I would like it to be highlighted in red, otherwise no highlighting.

What is a good way to accomplish this? Should I extend `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`? Implement my own custom `TreeCellRenderer`? Some other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the custom rendering you want to do is pretty basic, I would just extend `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` and override its `getTreeCellRendererComponent` method. You could simply adjust the foreground color on the `JLabel` that the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` uses. Here's a quick example:

```
tree.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {
  @Override
  public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded,
                                                boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
    YourNode node = (YourNode)value;
    if (node.isFlagged())
      label.setForeground(Color.RED);

    return label;
  }
});
```

And the result:
[image]