# JTree: how to get the Font/text color of the node?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have the following code:

```
tree = getTreeComponent(BLA)

model = tree.getModel();
root = tree.getModel().getRoot();
childCount = tree.getModel().getChildCount(root);

childList = tree.getModel().getChild(root,x);

print childList
```

I can get the tree node as a Text but not the Color of Font/Text node.

Could you give me suggestions?

Comment: *"could you give me please suggestions?"*  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)  This sounds like one of them.

Answer (score 4):

The appearance of the nodes is separated from the model. [`TreeCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html) is responsible to render the nodes of the tree which can be set using [`JTree.setCellRenderer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setCellRenderer-javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer-).

So if you want to know the `Font` and `Color` of a node, you should consult the renderer of the `JTree`. For example:

```
Component c = tree.getCellRenderer()
    .getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, node, false, false, false, 0, false);

Font font = c.getFont();         // Font used to render the node
Color color = c.getForeground(); // Foreground Color used to render the node
```

The renderer's [`getTreeCellRendererComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html#getTreeCellRendererComponent-javax.swing.JTree-java.lang.Object-boolean-boolean-boolean-int-boolean-) returns a [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) which will be used to paint the node.

The parameters of the `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` are:

```
JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus
```

Passing different values to these parameters may result in the returned `Component` having different `Font` and/or `Color`. Specify meaningful parameter values (e.g. it should not be selected as it usually inverts the colors, it should not have focus as it might also change the color).

Comment: Can you please explain the Parameters (tree, node, false, false, false, 0, false); ?

Comment: @maxf Read the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html)

Comment: You should also add that changing the parameters can change the result, as the node might change its appearance based on the parameters passed to the method ;)

Comment: Good answer though ;)

Comment: Thank you for Help :) I'm still learning java swing, can you please write me the Example for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111483/highlighting-specific-nodes-in-a-jtree-depending-on-data-stored-in-the-node

Comment: but with get function, i cant anderstand how do I get to the required node "Test1"

Comment: @icza def tree = rc.getComponent("xxxxx")
def renderer = tree.getCellRenderer();
def Component c = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,0, false, false, false, 3, false) , i have always error: "avax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer$getTreeCellRendererComponent(call:-1)"